# C sharp calls Java using cmd

Tags: c#, java, call

I am trying to write a c sharp program to call a jar file.

I've searched for a lot of solutions about this type of question, but I just can't figure it out.

Here is my situation, before really calling my jar file, I try to call java -version for a test.

This is a method that executes command line with the arguments cmd

```
public static string StartCmdProcess(string[] cmd)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.Start();
            p.StandardInput.AutoFlush = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < cmd.Length; i++)
            {
                p.StandardInput.WriteLine(cmd[i].ToString());
            }
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
            string strRst = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();
            p.Close();
            return strRst;
        }
```

and in my main method

I call

```
string result = StartCmdProcess(new string[] { "java -version" });
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

When I call "java", it works fine and outputs everything that's supposed to be printed.

But, when I put my arguments like java -version, it just doesn't work.

Is there anyone knows what is wrong with this problem?

Greatly appreciated if anyone could help :)

**EDITED:** The result of calling actually goes to StandardError rather than StandardOutput, but that's pretty wired. Anyone knows why?

```
public static string StartCmdProcess(string[] cmd)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.Start();
            p.StandardInput.AutoFlush = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < cmd.Length; i++)
            {
                p.StandardInput.WriteLine(cmd[i].ToString());
            }
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
            strRst.Append(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()).Append(p.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
            p.WaitForExit();
            p.Close();
            return strRst.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Actually, this calling works, but the result goes to StandardError instead of StandardOutput. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your arguments seperate from your command.

```
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
 p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-version";
```

When I tested this the output was redirected but it came from the standard error rather than the standard output. Unsure as to why but you could return both streams like so:

```
 StringBuilder strRst = new StringBuilder();
 strRst.AppendLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
 strRst.AppendLine(p.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
 p.WaitForExit();
 p.Close();
 return strRst.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have tested it as well, the result goes to  StandardError instead of StandardOutput. It's really wired, but at least I know it works. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your method to make use of the **cmd** parameter as follows

```
public static string StartCmdProcess(string[] cmd)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            FileName = cmd[0],
            Arguments = cmd.Length>1?cmd[1]:"",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
        }
     };
     p.Start();
     p.StandardInput.AutoFlush = true;
     for (int i = 0; i < cmd.Length; i++)
     {
         p.StandardInput.WriteLine(cmd[i].ToString());
     }
     p.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
     string strRst = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
     p.WaitForExit();
     p.Close();
     return strRst;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. the result of calling " java -version " from c sharp using cmd goes to StandardError instead of StandardOutput. It's wired.

Comment: Can you edit the code block in the question with the new code. You can add it to your existing question separated by EDIT text